# deleting label from image in html code

Tags: php, html, xml, rss, simplepie

I am extracting some rss feed. From each resource I get the description node that contain html code.

From this code I delete img tag with this code:

```
preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content)
```

After I would delete the image label that is after images.
For example in this code I would remove  elements.

```
<img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/06-2012/paolo-savona-lerner-170816_tn.jpg" alt="" id="394669"></em><strong>PAOLO SAVONA DA LERNER ALL INFEDELE </strong>
```

Xml:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<p><strong>Enrico Marro per "<a href="http://www.corriere.it/" target="_blank">Corriere della Sera</a>"</strong></p><span style="position: static; clear: none; z-index: auto; left: auto; top: auto;" class="imgDrag imgLeft"><em><img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/06-2012/paolo-savona-lerner-17
]]>
<![CDATA[
0816_tn.jpg" alt="" id="394669"></em><strong>PAOLO SAVONA DA LERNER ALL INFEDELE </strong></span>
 <p>«A dire il vero il piano del Pdl, cioè il piano Brunetta al quale pure abbiamo fornito materiali, è molto più soft della mia proposta, inizialmente elaborata col professor Giuseppe Guarino e mes
]]>
<![CDATA[
sa a punto in questi ultimi mesi con i colleghi Michele Fratianni e Antonio Rinaldi. Ma è pur sempre meglio che niente, purché l'azione choc per abbattere di 400 miliardi di euro il debito pubblico si faccia in un colpo solo e non frazionandola in più anni».</p>
 <p>Per Paolo Savona, economista,
]]>
<![CDATA[
presidente del Fondo interbancario di tutela dei depositi ed ex ministro dell'Industria nel governo Ciampi (1993-94), servirebbe un vero e proprio consolidamento di tutto il debito pubblico assistito dalla messa in gioco di asset del patrimonio pubblico destinati a essere ceduti.</p><span style="po
]]>
<![CDATA[
sition: static; clear: none; z-index: auto; left: auto; top: auto;" class="imgDrag imgRight"><em><img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/05-2010/57722_tn.jpg" alt="" id="282222"></em><strong>PAOLO SAVONA E SIGNORA </strong></span>
 <p><strong>Professore di proposta choc in proposta choc. Non si può fare altrimenti?</strong><br>«Teniamo presente che per via del debito che ha raggiunto quasi il 130% del Prodotto interno lordo noi paghiamo 3 punti percentuali in più di interessi sui titoli di Stato, il famoso spread, e questo in parte si riflette anche sul costo del denaro per l'attività produttiva. Occorre quindi sottrarsi a questa valutazione della speculazione.</p><span style="position: static; clear: none; z-index: auto; left: auto; top: auto;" class="imgDrag imgLeft"><em><img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/08-2012/italia-crisi-183522_tn.jpg" alt="" id="407340"></em><strong>italia crisi </strong></span>
 <p>Dico speculazione perché il patrimonio pubblico a garanzia del debito pubblico è più che capiente: fu censito prudenzialmente in quasi duemila miliardi di euro di valore dal ministero dell'Economia (commissione Reviglio junior) nel 2011, comprendendo anche le partecipazioni pubbliche e il patrimonio degli enti locali, che certamente non si possono tirar fuori da questo problema. Per fermare la speculazione bisogna consolidare e liberarci di questa palla al piede che frena lo sviluppo del Paese».</p><span style="position: static; clear: none; z-index: auto; left: auto; top: auto;" class="imgDrag imgRight"><em><img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/08-2012/italia-crisi-183521_tn.jpg" alt="" id="407339"></em><strong>italia crisi </strong></span>
 <p><strong>È una prospettiva che spaventa. Come funziona la sua proposta?</strong><br>«Innanzitutto si tratta di un'operazione di consolidamento su base volontaria. I titoli pubblici emessi dal Tesoro in circolazione vedrebbero la loro scadenza rimodulata a sette anni, indipendentemente dalla tipologia e dalla vita residua e gli interessi verrebbero rideterminati annualmente sulla base del costo della vita e del 20 per cento del tasso di crescita del Pil reale.</p>
 <p>Inoltre, per ogni mille euro di valore nominale di emissione di ciascun titolo oggetto del provvedimento sarebbe assegnato uno warrant negoziabile sul mercato durante i sette anni di vita del titolo sia per trarre un beneficio monetario immediato sia per opzionare i beni e le attività finanziarie messi a disposizione dallo Stato».</p><span style="position: static; clear: none; z-index: auto; left: auto; top: auto;" class="imgDrag imgLeft"><em><img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/04-2013/euro-crac-231641_tn.jpg" alt="" id="455060"></em><strong>EURO CRAC</strong></span>
 <p><strong>Ma non si creerebbe uno scenario argentino?</strong><br>«No. Durante i 7 anni del consolidamento il Tesoro non dovrebbe più finanziarsi emettendo titoli, dovrebbe rispettare il pareggio di bilancio e beneficerebbe del calo degli interessi sul debito di almeno 30 miliardi di euro all'anno, rispetto agli 85 che paghiamo ora, risparmi che per esempio potrebbero essere ben utilizzati per abbattere il cuneo fiscale sui salari.</p>
 <p>L'operazione dovrebbe essere strutturata giuridicamente e finanziariamente da società specializzate a livello internazionale che, ovviamente dietro adeguate commissioni, ne garantirebbero però il successo».</p><span style="position: static; clear: none; z-index: auto; left: auto; top: auto;" class="imgDrag imgRight"><em><img src="http://www.dagospia.com/img/foto/08-2012/italia-crisi-183520_tn.jpg" alt="" id="407338"></em><strong>italia crisi </strong></span>
 <p><strong>Perché un risparmiatore dovrebbe accettare volontariamente il consolidamento?</strong><br>«Perché sarebbe ben remunerato e acquisirebbe anche il warrant negoziabile sul mercato, cioè il diritto di beneficiare di vantaggi monetari cedendolo o di acquistare l'asset pubblico sottostante posto a garanzia che con la valorizzazione potrebbe essere molto appetibile».</p>
 <p><strong>Professore, mi pare un'operazione senza precedenti, in nessun Paese.</strong><br>«È vero. Si tratta di una pura operazione finanziaria che bypassa le resistenze delle burocrazie pubbliche che finora hanno ostacolato qualsiasi tentativo di attacco al debito. In ogni caso, ripeto, se la nostra ultima proposta sembra troppo ardita, si parta pure con quella rilanciata ora dal Pdl, purché in una tornata unica e non sia affidata alle burocrazie, altrimenti non decollerà mai.</p>
 <p>Si individuino gli asset per 400 miliardi di euro e li si conferiscano a una società privata ad hoc, abbattendo così il debito dai 2 mila miliardi attuali a 1.600 miliardi. Bisogna però sapere che questo non basta se poi si continua a fare deficit. Invece, col consolidamento che impone il ritiro dal mercato delle emissioni di nuovi titoli ci vuole il pareggio di bilancio e il problema del debito si avvia a una soluzione strutturale. Per attuarlo occorrono politici e tecnici coraggiosi e non cinici, ossia che non tollerino una disoccupazione che superi perfino i livelli attuali».</p>
 <p> </p>
]]>
</description>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like every `<img>` is wrapped inside an `<em>` tag, you certainly want to remove it along.

Interesting that you managed to get so far and be stuck at this stage. Anyways, try this regex:

```
/<em><img[^>]+\><\/em>\<strong>[^>]+>/i
```

This only works if the `<strong>` tag does not contain any sub-tag.

*Disclaimer: HTML is not a regular language*

Comment: ok it is removed...but If I would extract the content of 
<strong>content</strong>

Comment: Something like this, with `$input` being your unmodified input stream:  `preg_match_all('/<em><img[^>]+\><\/em>\<strong>([^<]+)<\/strong>/i' , $input, $matches); print_r($matches);`. Please check [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for an explanation. But this is definitely no task for a RegEx, you should look into something like [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) instead.